# how to implement gradle condition dependencies?

Tags: gradle

I am compile java project(Java 8) using gradle(Gradle 6.0),but my javafx path is differenct in local machine and remote compile server? in maven I specify path in remote server like this:

[image]

how to specify different path in local gradle.build and remote gradle.build,is any conditional dependencies write pattern in gradle?I want gradle to use different config in differenet enviroment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51154365/175554 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/37182892/175554 may solve your question

Comment: thank you!that's what I want@özkanpakdil

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conditional dependencies in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153878/conditional-dependencies-in-gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://stackoverflow.com/a/51154365/175554 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/37182892/175554 may solve your question.